# How to print pdf file on Windows 8.1-10? Print and printto verbs working no more?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, command-line, printing

How to print pdf document from code on Windows 8-10 ?
I get next exception: `Additional information: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.` 
when I make proc.Start(). It's becuase I try to call not exe, but pdf file.

This approach was working on Windows 7. On newer versions it doesn't work.

```
private void SendToPrinter()
    {
      var proc = new Process
        {
            string fileName = "c:\output.pdf"
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Verb = "printto",
                FileName = fileName,
                Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForInputIdle();

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        if (!proc.HasExited && !proc.CloseMainWindow())
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
```

I tried to do it from console, typeing like :

```
"c:\output.pdf" printto "PDFCreator"
```

or like this:

```
"c:\output.pdf" -verb printto "PDFCreator"
```

*printto* verb is not working at all, just opens Foxit Reader,
 and *print* verb says "is currently been printed" if I type like this

```
print "c:\output.pdf" "PDFCreator"
```

but nothing heppens
I tried not only with printing to file, but with normal printer too. JPG prints from code very well, but not pdf.